# Correct way to end GKTurnBasedMatch out of turn

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, game-center

Let's say there is a GKTurnBasedMatch with only 2 participants left that haven't quit yet.

If the current participant wants to quit, instead of calling, `participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome:...` is it correct to call, `endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:...` since the match can't continue with only one participant?

But if the other participant wants to quit, you can't call `endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:...` since it is not your turn, so you would have to call `participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome:...` but then you are left with a single participant in the match.

What is the correct way to handle these situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call `–participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome:withCompletionHandler:` then `-(void)handleTurnEventForMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match didBecomeActive:(BOOL)didBecomeActive`  from `GKTurnBasedEventHandlerDelegate` will be called for all other participants.

There you can call `-(void)endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:(NSData *)matchData completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionHandler` for player whose turn is now.

To determine, who left your match, check GKTurnBasedParticipant's property matchOutcome - it will be GKTurnBasedMatchOutcomeQuit.